# is it possible to read a Map<String,List<String>> from yaml in Java

Tags: java, yaml

I have a login check whitelist for different app in my gateway, the config of yaml may look lik this:

```
dolphin:
  gateway:
    login-check-path:
      exclude:
        app1:
          - /login
          - /signin
        app2:
          - /login1
          - /signin1
```

Now I want to read this `excude` as `Map<String,List<String>>` data structure. This is the read config right now:

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * @author xiaoqiangjiang
 */
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "dolphin.gateway.login-check-path")
@Component
public class LoginExcludeUrl {

    private Map<String,List<String>> exclude = new HashMap<>();

    public List<String> getExclude(String appPrev) {
        return exclude.get(appPrev);
    }

}
```

now the exclude read 0 element. Am I missing something? is it possible to read the yaml multi subelment as Map? what I expect is that the exclude map contains two keys `app1` and `app2` and each key contains 2 elements. this is my startup class:

```
package com.example.demo;


import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;

/**
 * @author xiaoqiangjiang
 */
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties({LoginExcludeUrl.class})
public class DemoApplicationSlim {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplicationSlim.class, args);
    }
}
```

I have tried to specify the path like this:

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * @author xiaoqiangjiang
 */
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "dolphin.gateway.login-check-path")
@Component
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:application.yaml")
public class LoginExcludeUrl {

    private Map<String,List<String>> exclude;

    public List<String> getExclude(String appPrev) {
        return exclude.get(appPrev);
    }

    public void setExclude(Map<String, List<String>> exclude) {
        this.exclude = exclude;
    }
}
```

but still could not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a setter for the `exclude` field in the `ConfigurationProperties`.

```java
public void setExclude(Map<String, List<String>> exclude) {
    this.exclude = exclude;
}
```

Comment: I have tried what you said seems did not work.

Comment: @Dolphin I can't reproduce it then. This change works when I tested it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, here is an example with Spring.

My java

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:myyaml.yml", factory = YamlPropertySourceFactory.class)
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class YamlConfig {

    private Map<String, HashMap<String, List<String>>>   map= new HashMap<>();
```

my yaml file

```
 userRightsMap:
    RWD:
      -read:
        - all
      -write:
        - all
      -delete:
        - all
    RWD:
      -read:
        - b
      -write:
        - b
      -delete:
        - b
```

My yaml read config

```
public class YamlPropertySourceFactory implements PropertySourceFactory {

    @Override
    public PropertySource<?> createPropertySource(String name, EncodedResource encodedResource) throws IOException {
        YamlPropertiesFactoryBean factory = new YamlPropertiesFactoryBean();
        factory.setResources(encodedResource.getResource());
        Properties properties = factory.getObject();
        return new PropertiesPropertySource(encodedResource.getResource().getFilename(), properties);
    }

}
```